# yadcf error: Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of null at addRangeDateFilter

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I'm running into the following issue:

```
jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:1834 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of null
    at addRangeDateFilter (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:1834)
    at appendFilters (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:3033)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:3768)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:4121)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:4350)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4901)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js:4900)
```

This only occurs when I navigate to some other page and then come back to the old page. I am alo using range date filter on other pages with single datatables but this error doesn't come up. However on this page there are multiple datatables, so that might be a possible cause.

I'm using the following code:

```
yadcf.init(table, [           
{
 column_number: 5,
 filter_container_id: 'dateFilter',
 filter_type: 'range_date'
}],
{externally_triggered: true});
```

On loading the page initially there is no error but once I navigate back to this page after visiting some other page, this error comes up.

Is there any method to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old version of jquery running, updated the library and this got fixed.